# Is this the correct way to calculate the availability of a web site by using all non-5xx http status codes / all status codes?

Tags: http, http-status-codes, availability

I was asked to calculate the availability of a web site by using a simple way: use all the non-5xx http status codes / all status codes.

Is this correct? I'm new to this concept, so any response is welcome:).

Comment: What do you mean with 'Use non 5xx http status codes', your question is unclear.

Comment: @Evert, it means that status code not starts with 5, like 301，200，404

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but what do you mean with 'use'. Perhaps you could try to just edit your question and phrase it in a different way. I suspect it's an easily answerable question but it's hard to understand right now.

Comment: Do you mean to ask something like: "Is it enough to check for 5xx status codes to determine if a service is unavailable?"

Comment: @Evert, yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: then I would say.. mostly yes, but there's other failure modes like your connection being refused, connection timing out that *don't* give you a HTTP status code but the server is still definitely broken.

Comment: @Evert, thanks for your reply:). Could you please post an answer?